# Merge multiple rows into one column using carriage return line feeds

Tags: sql-server

The code below (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645297/merge-multiple-rows-into-one-column-without-duplicates/12645346?noredirect=1#comment22037856_12645346) ) does a good job at merging together multiple fields separating them with commas.

```
select player,
  stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(score as varchar(10))
       FROM yourtable t2
       where t2.player = t1.player
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from yourtable t1
group by player
```

I need to replace the commas with carriage return line feeds. I tried the code below but it started separating the entries with these characters: "#x0D;"

```
select player,
  stuff((SELECT distinct CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(score as varchar(10))
       FROM yourtable t2
       where t2.player = t1.player
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from yourtable t1
group by player
```

I suspect the problem is with the "FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''" but I don't know what values to put.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually replace the comma on the result of STUFF.

Try this:

```
select player,
  replace(stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(score as varchar(10))
       FROM yourtable t2
       where t2.player = t1.player
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''), ',', char(13) + char(10))
from yourtable t1
group by player
```

Comment: how about going new line instead of comma?

Answer (score 4):

You can handle all the special characters that XML adds (of which `#x0D;` is one) by using:

```
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

More information [here](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/).

You will also need to adjust the third parameter of `STUFF` to the number of characters you need to skip at the start of your result (in this case to 2 because you have `char(13)` and `char(10)`).

So your solution would be:

```
select player,
  stuff((SELECT distinct CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(score as varchar(10))
       FROM yourtable t2
       where t2.player = t1.player
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') 
from yourtable t1
group by player
```